# Determinant of large square matrix (term by term multiplication with same size matrix)

Tags: determinant, symmetric-matrices

M is an N by N matrix with coefficients $a_{ij}$, B an N by N matrix with coefficients $b_{ij}$. Both M and B are symmetric matrices. I am trying to write the determinat of a matrix say, M .* B where B is of the same size and .* represents term by term multiplication. If we write the determinant of M as :

$\det(M) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \left( sgn(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma_i}\right)$

Is it possible to write the determinant of C = M .* B as :

$\det(C) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \left( sgn(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n b_{i,\sigma_i} a_{i,\sigma_i}\right)$

I just realized my problem may be more complicated. I have a matrix M that depends on a paramater $\rho$ with each entry being $exp(-\rho d_{ij})$ and all diagonal elements equal to 1. So the determinant can be written as : $det(M(\rho)) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \left( sgn(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n exp(-\rho d_{i,\sigma_i})\right)$

So the derivative of the determinant wrt $\rho$ gives

$det'(M(\rho)) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \left( sgn(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n d_{i,\sigma_i} exp(-\rho d_{i,\sigma_i})\right)$.

Is it possible to express this as the determiannt of some matrix that depends on M ?

Comment: Yes because the matrix elements can be anything, $a_{ij}$, or $a_{ij} b_{ij}$ or $\text{whatever}_{ij}$. But that doesn't lead to a simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is fine. To see this, note that $c_{i,j}=a_{i, j}b_{i, j}$ for all $i, j$. Hence $c_{i,\sigma(i)} = a_{i,\sigma(i)} b_{i,\sigma(i)}$ for all $i$ and all $\sigma \in S_n$. Using this and the determinant formula will give you the desired result.

Comment: Yes you are right ! I just added some details to the question. My problem is a bit more complicated as explained in the edit.

Comment: It seems like you now want to find the derivative of the determinant of a matrix. In that case, this page may be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula.